# Приложение падает на SetcontentView(Мое активити), в котором используются наследники от Button

Tags: java, android, activity

Создала свой класс `SapperButton extends Button`, во вьюхе накидала таких кнопок этого вида. При просмотре дезайнера выдается окно с

```
The following class could not be found - SapperButton
```

А после запуска при переходе на соответствующий лейоут с этой вьюхой все падает.
Понимаю, что не может найти мой класс-наследник от `Button`. Но почему и как это исправить?

Вот начало активити, из которого вызывается вьюха:

```
package com.example.helen.mygamesapper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


    int numBombs;
    Button[][] fields;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        TextView numBombText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numBombText);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        numBombs = intent.getIntExtra("numBombs", 10);
```

Вот мой класс-наследник от кнопки:

```
package com.example.helen.mygamesapper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;
public class SapperButton extends Button {

    private boolean isOpen = false;
    private boolean isBomb = false;
    private boolean isBlown = false;
/*
    public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
*/
    public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public SapperButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }




    public boolean isOpen()
    {
        return isOpen;
    }

    public void setOpen(boolean open)
    {
        isOpen = open;
    }
    public void setBomb(boolean bomb)
    {
        isBomb = bomb;
    }

    public boolean getIsBomb()
    {
        return isBomb;
    }


    public boolean isBlown()
    {
        return isBlown;
    }

    public void setBlowned(boolean isBlowning)
    {
        isBlown = isBlowning;
    }

}
```

Сама вьюха:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/numBombs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:paddingTop="5pt"
        android:paddingBottom="5pt"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numBombText"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/numBombs"
        android:id="@+id/lin123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:paddingTop="5pt"
        android:paddingBottom="5pt"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Лог ошибки:

> 03-26 16:24:52.044 9706-9706/com.example.helen.mygamesapper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.helen.mygamesapper, PID: 9706
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helen.mygamesapper/com.example.helen.mygamesapper.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class SapperButton
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class SapperButton
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:312)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1952)
>                                                                                         at com.example.helen.mygamesapper.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SapperButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.helen.mygamesapper-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.helen.mygamesapper-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:312) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1952) 
>                                                                                         at com.example.helen.mygamesapper.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Для ответа нам нужно ваш класс посмотреть, разметку, тип ошибки. И превью глючный - не используйте его вообще.

Comment: Выложила классы и вьюху

Comment: а в логах какая ошибка?

Comment: скопировала лог

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос решил проблему, изложенную в вопросе, отметьте его верным. По новой проблеме создайте новый вопрос, не редактируйте старый вопрос так, что теряется его первоначальный смысл. Дело в том, что этот вопрос поможет кому то еще решить аналогичную проблему в будущем. Если он будет исправлен с описанием другой проблемы, то вопрос и ответ не будут соответствовать и он будет бесполезен в дальнейшем.Данный ресурс Q&A, а не форум, цель такого ресурса - создать базу рабочих переиспользуемых решений, а не ограничиваться помощью одному человеку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для [кастомных `View`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/create-view.html) в разметке xml нужно указывать полный путь до класса:

```
 <com.example.helen.mygamesapper.SapperButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Переделала вьюху, сейчас даже билд не создается. Лог в главном посте.

Comment: Сделала минимальный API 16 вместо 15, сейчас в дезайнере все отображается, но теперь подсвечивает красным все R  в Activity, и при попытке сбилдить выдает последний лог из первого поста.

Comment: чтобы студия нашла R нужно сделать Build ==> Clean Project

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich не помогло

Comment: @pavlofff 23 и так было, SDK установила все от 15 версии, задем ребилдила проект, не помогло.

Comment: Я создала новый проект, скопировала туда коды моих классов и вьюх, переделала во вьюхе с кнопками на com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton , все равно валится на том же самом месте, лог самый последний.

Comment: Спасибо, что поддержали порядок в правках вопроса.