# Как приводить наследника от Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Хочу унаследоваться от Floating Action Button в отдельный класс, чтобы определить в этом классе всё, что связано в этой кнопкой.

```
public class MainViewFAB extends FloatingActionButton {

    public MainViewFAB(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

}
```

Но как правильно привести тип при создании экземпляра объекта?

- При таком приведении:

  ```
  fab = (MainViewFAB) findViewById(R.id.mainViewTab);
  ```

  среда разработки ошибок не выдаёт, но при запуске возникает исключение

  ```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to com.example.MainViewFAB
  ```
- Если привести

  ```
  fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.mainViewTab);
  ```

  то среда выдаст

  ```
  Incompatible Types; Requierd: MainViewFAB, Found: FloatingActionButton
  ```
- Если же ничего не приводить, то среда выдаст

  ```
  Incompatible Types; Requierd: MainViewFAB, Found: View
  ```

Comment: а fab какого типа? и сам клас откомпилировать удается?

Comment: findViewById что за метод

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь привести класс `FloatingActionButton` ( судя по ошибке так и есть) к своему классу `MainViewFAB` то у вас, естественно, ничего не получится. То есть, если на разметке у вас FAB, а не ваш `MainViewFAB`, то приведение невозможно. Либо разметсите на разметку ваш виджет, либо приводите FAB к FAB, а не  к вашему виджету.

Comment: @pavloff, а как именно добавить в разметку виджет, унаследованный не от `View`? Если добавить `<view class="com.example.MainViewFAB"`, то ошибка останется.

Comment: `<com.example.MainViewFAB ...`

Comment: @Vladimir Parfenov Пробовал; падает с той же ошибкой. Может какие атрибуты нужны?

Comment: в общем то ответ уже есть, [аналогичный вопрос и решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506892/177345) так же ссылка на гайд по созданию кастомных View

Comment: @pavloff Спасибо за информацию. Принял к сведению. К сожалению, не прочитал эти пункты. Извиняюсь за дезинформацию. Руководствовался тем принципом, что есть участники, которые задают вопрос, сами на него отвечают (умышленно, а не честно в итоге находя ответ) и собирают баллы репутации.

Comment: @Vladimir Parfenov  А это разве противоправно? Даже если автор изначально знает ответ на свой вопрос, его могут не знать начинающие, и они смогут найти его на данном форуме вне зависимости от того, кто ответил. Главное, чтобы вопрос и ответ были качественными.

Comment: Давайте не будет дискуссировать на эту тему. Правила есть правила. А я лишь руководствовался тем, что здесь все же вопросник. Пользователь задает вопрос в надежде получить ответ. Если он нашел решение, то согласно правилам, пусть публикует ответ. Но, если это ради того, чтобы набить репутацию, то я могу хоть весь день публиковать такие вопросы и отвечать на них. Не очень честно как-то.

Comment: @pavloff Я и не говорил, что может. Я лишь говорю, что могу сидеть так и поднимать себе весь день репутацию на русскоязычном портале. Задавать качественные вопросы и качественно отвечать, и ответы будут оцениваться другими. Просто переводить англ версию на русскую. Не считаю, что это хороший подход в данном сервисе.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov для окончательного прояснения [обсуждение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2292/177345) по этому случаю. Так же обсуждение на мете по переводам с английского ресурса - это [тоже приветствуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/177345) и репутация так же будет заслуженной. Единственное, не хотелось бы видеть переводы и вопросы\ответы, на которые уже есть качественные решения на данном ресурсе (дубликаты). Если у вас есть сомнения по какому то поводу, вы можете поднять обсуждение на Мете. Предлагаю удалить комментарии не относящиеся к сути самого вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

При создании кастомного `view` в `layout` необходимо указать класс вместе с пакетом. В Вашем случае будет примерно так:

```
<com.example.MainViewFAB
    ... />
```

И далее:

```
MainViewFAB fab = (MainViewFAB) findViewById(R.id.mainViewTab);
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину. В конструкторе есть только контекст, а надо ещё `AttributeSet`.

```
public MainViewFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
}
```

Разметка и приведение типов - как указал @post_zeew в другом ответе.