# Android: Binary XML file line XX: Error inflating class при присвоении поведения BottomSheet

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk

В вопросе [Android: как приводить наследника от Floating Action Button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673143/android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-floating-action-button#comment980582_673143) рассматривалась ошибка

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to com.example.MainViewFAB
```

В том случае ошибка исчезла путём добавления `AttributeSet` в конструктор наследника `FloatingActionButton`.

На этот раз я решил унаследоваться от `TableLayout` и возникла ошибка

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.MyBottomSheet
```

**MyFragment.java**

У меня приложение с вкладками, каждой из которой соответствует отдельный фрагмент. Поэтому я добавляю разметку только в нужном фрагменте:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.my_fragment;
    private myBottomSheet addNewItemToInboxBottomSheet;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        myBottomSheet =  (myBottomSheet) activity.findViewById(R.id.myBottomSheetWrapper);
        return inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

    }

}
```

**my_bottom_sheet_wrapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.MyBottomSheet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myBottomSheetWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <TableRow>
        <!-- ... -->
    </TableRow>

</com.example.MyBottomSheet>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- ... -->

        <include layout="@layout/my_bottom_sheet"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MyBottomSheet.java**

Если из приведённого ниже кода убрать строку

```
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(this);
```

приложение не упадёт (но и управлять `BottomSheet` программно будет нельзя).

```
public class MyBottomSheet extends TableLayout{

    BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;

    public MyBottomSheet(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context,attributeSet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior=BottomSheetBehavior.from(this); // вылет здесь
    }
}
```

---

### Ссылка на исходники

В период проведения конкурса доступна [ссылка на исходники](https://yadi.sk/d/r2Mn50iL3JsBv7).

Comment: Ошибся с разметкой ссылки, правильная ссылка на исходники [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/r2Mn50iL3JsBv7).

Answer (score 2):

Вьюха у вас в разметке фрагмента, а вы ищете её в разметке активити. Это разные вещи. Делайте так:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private MyBottomSheet myBottomSheet;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        myBottomSheet =  (MyBottomSheet) v.findViewById(R.id.myBottomSheetWrapper); // table layout

        return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибок нет; всё работает. Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Comment: Прошу прощения, к сожалению, упустил один момент, забыв убрать комментарий с `mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(this);`. `BottomSheet` у меня теперь в разметке активити (иначе он не будет открываться). Ошибка продолжает возникать. Может, причина в другом? Экземпляр класса-то создаётся.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, задайте новый вопрос с актуальной разметкой и классом с ошибкой

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, ну так теперь ищите его в `Activity`, как раньше

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб, новый вопрос по теме не будет отличаться от этого. Поэтому я отредактировал код в поле вопроса.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, попробуйте `app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"` перенести в разметку активити

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к какому именно тэгу добавить эти атрибуты?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, к тому же самому. Который там в виде `include`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, то есть добавить эти атрибуты к `include`? Если так, то это не работает.